# SSRS dynamic addition of columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a list of employees having emp id, name, designation, age and salary. I need to change the columns to show from report using parameters. selected columns only will be included. How can I implement it with SSRS?

Comment: Do you mean add a parameter that can be used to hide columns?

Comment: Your answer is **Cascading Parameters**

Comment: Yes I meant to add a parameter to hide columns

Comment: cascading parameters do not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this straight, you want to hide a column (probably salary) based on who runs the report. There are a few components involved,

1. Figuring out who is running the report (Optional)

If you are using domain auth, or the user has a signon to the SSRS portal, you can use the built in field for the UserID to identify the user, assign it to a parameter to be cascaded to a data set to determine if they can view salaries. So you right click on parameters click add, name it Login, set the parameter visibility to internal, leave available values as none, set the default value to

```
=User!UserID
```

This step is optional because you can surface the upcoming visibility parameter rather than cascade it based on user, depending on how you call the report that may be your best option. However if you are doing a cascade, **The Login has to be the first parameter for these types of cascades or the report will crash**, you can move it up in SSDT or BIDS by clicking on the parameter and clicking on the up arrow.

2. Finding out if they have permission to see salaries (Optional)

Now that we have the user ID we feed it into a data set, prior to this you should have created a table that lists user IDs, and whether or not they can see salaries. Create a data set named something like SalaryVisibleToUser

```
Select isnull(CanSeeSalaries, 0) as CanSeeSalaries 
From YourReportDB.DBO.ReportUserPermissions
where userid = @Login
```

You can drop the isnull if you would prefer the report to crash if you haven't added the user to that table, but I prefer access restriction to be done by permissions rather than error, YMMV.

3. Finish the Cascade, and/or set the salary visibility parameter.

So now we have a data set telling us whether or not the user can see salaries, Next we Create a parameter named SalariesVisible, set it to internal if you are cascading it, or hidden if you are going to pass it. Leave available values as none, and set the default value to get values from query, select the data set SalaryVisibleToUser, then select CanSeeSalaries as the value column.

4. Set the column visibility based on SalariesVisible parameter.

Right click on the column in BIDS/SSDT click on column visibility, click on show or hide based on expression, then click on the F of X button. then set the expression to

```
=Iif(Parameters!SalariesVisible = 1, False, True)
```

This seems a little backwards, but you're telling it false to hide (ie: Visible) or true to hide (ie: Hidden). That about covers it, Good Luck!